# Link to specific content of different page in Angular 9

Tags: angular, redirect, routes, navigation, angular-ui-router

Let's say there are three categories on the webpage - Continent, Country, State.
I am currently working on a button which have been placed on a different page. I want when the button will be clicked my page will automatically redirect to the categories page and scroll to the third section i.e. State section.
I am a little new to Angular and have tried a lot's of methods mentioned over the other sites like using RouterLink, navigation, routes but nothing worked as per my expectation as per now.
Can someone please assist in this or share some already developed links.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Can you share your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It easy. Pass state in the router like this on the first page

```
<button [routerLink] = "['/page2', {pageSec: 'section2'}]">Go to section 2</button>

<br>
<br>

<button [routerLink] = "['/page2', {pageSec: 'section3'}]" >Go to Section 3</button>
```

Then on the second page, Use the activated route to get the state object from the router.  Use the ViewChild decorator to communicate with the DOM. Subscribe to the Activated Route params Observable in ngAfterInit, get the parameter you need, and scroll into view. Check the snippet below to see what I mean

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-page2',
  templateUrl: './page2.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./page2.component.scss']
})
export class Page2Component implements AfterViewInit {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private activeRoute: ActivatedRoute, ) { }
  @ViewChild('container') container: ElementRef<HTMLElement>;

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {

    this.activeRoute.params.subscribe(param => {
      // alert(param.pageSec)
      if(param.pageSec){
        const section = this.container.nativeElement.querySelector(`#${param.pageSec}`)
        console.log(section)

        section?.scrollIntoView()
      }
    })

  }

}
```

On Page2 Html make and a selector. In this example, I made my selector container. Then give each of your sections an id. The id is what your wound scroll into.
Your html should look like this.

```
<div #container>

  ............
  <div id="section1">
    .......
  </div>

  <div id="section2">
    ....
  </div>

  <div id="section3">
    .....
  </div>
</div>
```

And that's it!!!!. Make sure you use ngAfterInit instead of ngOninit, Because The Dom elements won't be available immediately after you initialize the component

Comment: Thanks buddy. It worked like charm. 
I almost invested 12-13 hours before posting it here but it didn't worked. Now it's working fine.

Comment: Would you be able to point me to the Angular Documentation where this concept have been enlisted?

Comment: Hey man, there is really no documentation on this concept. I needed to do something like this before that why I know it. Most of angular's api have something to do with rxjs, so if you embrace rxjs in your project, working with angular would be easy. Also anytime you want to work with the dom,  just know that you might have to use viewchild decorator. You can read on rxjs and also decorators.